# NullPointerException on setContentView() but it exists

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, setcontentview

I have an **adapter** class extended to BaseAdapter that starts another activity through intent. That another activity is giving me the error:

```
10-10 23:58:57.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3651): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.migdinny.passman/com.migdinny.passman.DataActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

...

```
10-10 23:58:57.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3651): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 23:58:57.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3651):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
10-10 23:58:57.171: E/AndroidRuntime(3651):     at com.migdinny.passman.DataActivity.onCreate(DataActivity.java:20)
```

Here's the code:

THE CODE THAT STARTS THE NEW ACTIVITY (this is inside a new listener)

```
            @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DataActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("category", category);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

THIS CODE IS THE NEW ACTIVITY THAT IS STARTED BY THE CODE ABOVE

```
public class DataActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String category;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // i've tried this line on all places and it doesnt fix the problem, after the setcontentview, before, etc
    Intent intent = getIntent(); // this works

    category = intent.getExtras().getString("category"); // this exists 

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data); // THIS IS THE LINE 20 OF DATA ACTIVITY and of course that the activity_data layout exists. the eclipse does not warn me anything.

}
........
```

EDIT:

here's the activity_data.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.migdinny.passman.DataActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

the category variable that is used on onClick:

```
final String category = list.get(position).getCatname(); // on the beginning of getView method and i think the error is not here
```

Comment: Post you activity_data xml layout

Comment: @forcewill what will that do for us?

Comment: since category is not a local variable to onClick, it must be a field, please show how it is set.

Comment: @codeMagic too much information is never bad since we're programmers and data is what we deal with on a daily basis, besides since the Exception is on line 20 where he sets the layout I thought it would make some sense to have the involved layout

Comment: @forcewill On a Q&A site such as this, too much data can be bad if it is irrelevant since it makes it harder to sift through and find the actual problem.

Comment: @codeMagic sorry, i'm not yelling at you, i'm used to write in caps lock for better understanding

Comment: @codeMagic i've tried to cleaning the project and it didnt work. how can i post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: the activity_data.xml is here. i edited the post.
@nPn i edited the post again. the category final variable is setted on the beginning of getView() which is the function that has the on click listener

Comment: Maybe this will be a little weird but i could solve it by extending  data activity from Activity and not from ActionBarActivity. I don't know why but anyway thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any custom theming? I remember reading somewhere someone with an issue related and was related to the mind, if you have try to remove it to see if it's related (worth at try)

Comment: thanks for the help but i could solve it by extending the data activity from Activity instead from ActionBarActivity. i don't know why really.